C++ typedef struct equivalent in C#
I am trying to convert some C++ code into C#
#pragma pack (push, 1)
  typedef struct od
  {
    unsigned short Reserved1;
    unsigned char  Reserved2;

    od()
      : Reserved1(0)
      , Reserved2(0)
    {}
  } OD;


  typedef struct PortValue
  {
    USHORT  pIndex;
    USHORT  value;
    ULONG32 ticks;

    PortValue()
      : pIndex(0)
      , value(0)
      , ticks(0)
    {}
  } PORT_VALUE, *PPORT_VALUE;


  typedef struct _API_Data
  {
    unsigned long  Ticks;
    unsigned long  SystemTime;
    unsigned short DisableNotification;
    unsigned short Reserved2;
    unsigned short NextValue;
    unsigned short Reserved3;
    PORT_VALUE     PortValues[500];
    OD             Reserved4;

    _API_Data()
      : Ticks(0)
      , SystemTime(0)
      , DisableNotification(0)
      , Reserved2(0)
      , NextValue(0)
      , Reserved3(0)
    {}
  } API_DATA, *PAPI_DATA;
#pragma pack (pop)

Here is what I have come up with for C#, but as you will see below it is not right
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public struct od
  {
    public ushort Reserved1;
    public byte   Reserved2;
  } OD;


  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public struct PortValue
  {
    public ushort  pIndex;
    public ushort  value;
    public uint    ticks;
  } PORT_VALUE, *PPORT_VALUE;


  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public struct _API_Data
  {
    uint       Ticks;
    uint       SystemTime;
    ushort     DisableNotification;
    ushort     Reserved2;
    ushort     NextValue;
    ushort     Reserved3;
    PORT_VALUE PortValues[500];
    OD         Reserved4;
  } API_DATA, *PAPI_DATA;

I know my C# code is wrong with how I am declaring the structs.
I don't know how to create the equivalent of the struct name and pointer to the struct.
I also don't know how to initialize the values like the C++ code does.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

why are you trying to keep the C# counterpart the same as in C++?

I also don't know how to initialize the values like the C++ code does. -- You initialize members in a C# struct the same way you always do in C#.  There is no need to look at how C++ initializes members.

C# structs don't have separate pointer / names like c++, just name the struct struct X to exactly what you want it to be called.

Also, typedef struct is a holdover from C.  In C++, there is no need for typedef struct, only struct.  What you have are not even C structs to begin with, since the structs contain a user-defined constructor, and those do not exist in C.  If this were C, you wouldn't be able to initialize any of those members like what you posted -- instead you would have to call a function to "zero out" all the members, for example, using memset.

How well do you know C++ and how well do you know C#. In general do NOT convert code from one language to another.  But try to understand what the C++ code is doing and then write new code in C#.

If your C++ code is calling a windows API function there is a good chance C# has some native code ... so can you tell us WHAT you're trying to do instead of asking is HOW to do something?

@Raildex To call the code from C++, I imagine (or vice versa)

Following up on @PepijnKramer's point, you should really describe your use case. I'm assuming it's to use these structs in some P/Invoke scenario. Your question should include the code that will consume these structs and describe what/why you are doing this

C# doesn't have an equivalent to typedef a struct, and you don't need to declare pointer aliases to a struct type anyway.
Try something more like this:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct OD
{
    public ushort Reserved1 = 0;
    public byte   Reserved2 = 0;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct PORT_VALUE
{
    public ushort pIndex = 0;
    public ushort value = 0;
    public uint   ticks = 0;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct API_DATA
{
    public uint   Ticks = 0;
    public uint   SystemTime = 0;
    public ushort DisableNotification = 0;
    public ushort Reserved2 = 0;
    public ushort NextValue = 0;
    public ushort Reserved3 = 0;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 500)]
    public PORT_VALUE[] PortValues = new PORT_VALUE[500];
    public OD Reserved4 = new OD();
}


Thank you Remy.  As always you are very helpful.
The only thing to add to your code above was an empty constructor was needed for each struct (e.g. public OD() {})

@Gary Why? That should not be needed, since the fields are being initialized directly.

The visual studio compiler wanted it and said it was an error without it.  "error CS8983: A 'struct' with field initializers must include an explicitly declared constructor."  Why VS insists on an empty constructor that does nothing I cannot say.
